# How to pass variables from controller to view

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

iam using codeigniter 2.2
The following is my controller class

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


public function index()
    {
     $test = "hello";
     $this->load->view('welcome_message',$test);
 }
}
```

The following is my view

```
<html><body><h1><?php echo  $data?></h1></body></html>
```

trying to pass a variable to the view keep getting  this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: views/welcome_message.php
>
> Line Number: 75

Comment: Where is `$data` set?

Comment: R.T.?.[Manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html)

Comment: cant we pass simple string variable to view?? i have tried the following code still getting the above error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
        {
            $test = "hello";
            $data['test'] = $test
            $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
        }
    }
}
```

in view

`<html><body><h1><?php echo $test; ?></h1></body></html>`

For more reference check https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: it keep saying   A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: views/welcome_message.php

Line Number: 75

Comment: @KevalRathi yes i have tried the above code keep giving me the same error. Actually i cant send any varriable to the view not even the string

Comment: @muhammadarslanTariq in you view code change <?php echo $data; ?> with <?php echo $test; ?>

Comment: @RohitGaikwad Yes it worked thank you so much.. just please tell cant we pass any string variable like $myvar="hello";    to the view and print it there? means in controller $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
and in view echo myvar;

Comment: You can use like this $data['test'] = "some string"

Comment: @RohitGaikwad yes , but iam not getting option to accept the answer plz tell me where to do so

Comment: @muhammadarslanTariq Just select check mark below votes.