# array prints result in controller but not giving result in view ,codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass data from controller to view page.. My query loaded from the model prints the result but when passed into view page, data not giving any result,instead it shows error:`Message: Undefined index: Country_id` .Why this really happens for.?

```
public function something()
{
$data['country']= $this->some_model->getCountry();
$this->load->view('another/location.php',$data);
//print_r($data['country']);
}
```

my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-4">Country*</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <?php  foreach ($country as $count) { ?>
            <option value="<?php  echo $count["Country_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $count["Country"]; ?></option>
            <?php  } ?>
            </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and model:

```
public function getCountry()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('tbl_country');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: Try using `print_r($country)` within your view file and check what you recieved at your view end

Comment: Also post your model and views code!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables from controller to view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474187/how-to-pass-variables-from-controller-to-view)

Comment: Post your model and view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print $country in view. Use echo ""; print_r($country);. I think you used foreach loop for data print and Country_id doesn't exist in database table column.So this error occured.

Comment: yeah..there is foreach loop in my view page..but it's printing the Country_id in controller.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for asking this question..Coz I used the wrong way to print the result.. <?php echo $count->Country_id; ?> which is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

In CodeIgniter, when you pass data from controller to view.

You can access the passed data with keys.

In your example, you are passing `$data['country']`.

So, in view, you need to print `echo '<pre>'print_r($country);echo '</pre>';`

Please check it this was correct in your case.